# Why is curl in Ruby slower than command-line curl?

Tags: ruby, http, curl, download, curb

I am trying to download more than 1m pages (URLs ending by a sequence ID). I have implemented kind of multi-purpose download manager with configurable number of download threads and one processing thread. The downloader downloads files in batches:

```
curl = Curl::Easy.new

batch_urls.each { |url_info|
    curl.url = url_info[:url]
    curl.perform
    file = File.new(url_info[:file], "wb")
    file << curl.body_str
    file.close
    # ... some other stuff
}
```

I have tried to download 8000 pages sample. When using the code above, I get 1000 in 2 minutes. When I write all URLs into a file and do in shell:

```
cat list | xargs curl
```

I gen all 8000 pages in two minutes.

Thing is, I need it to have it in ruby code, because there is other monitoring and processing code.

I have tried:

- Curl::Multi - it is somehow faster, but misses 50-90% of files (does not download them and gives no reason/code)
- multiple threads with Curl::Easy - around the same speed as single threaded

Why is reused Curl::Easy slower than subsequent command line curl calls and how can I make it faster? Or what I am doing wrong?

I would prefer to fix my download manager code than to make downloading for this case in a different way.

Before this, I was calling command-line wget which I provided with a file with list of URLs. Howerver, not all errors were handled, also it was not possible to specify output file for each URL separately when using URL list.

Now it seems to me that the best way would be to use multiple threads with system call to 'curl' command. But why when I can use directly Curl in Ruby?

Code for the download manager is here, if it might help: [Download Manager](http://github.com/Stiivi/Datacamp-ETL/blob/master/lib/etl/download_manager.rb) (I have played with timeouts, from not-setting it to various values, it did not seem help)

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: I've tried to create simple curl system call instead of Curl::Easy:

    result = system("curl", "-s", "-o", path, url)

 And it seems to be much much faster. I am getting around 300kb/s instead of 60kb/s with Curl::Easy.

It is weird - system call with huge system overhead and without connection reusing is much faster than library functions. CPU usage is much higher, obviously, however the speed is much better.

Anyway, this is still not nice solution to my problem, even though working better.

Comment: have you tried using more recent versions of curb with Curl::Multi.download interface?

Comment: `cat list | xargs curl` is passing many URLs to Curl on the command-line, instead of one at a time, so Curl is retrieving many at once. You can do that in Ruby easily enough, but you need to compare apples to apples and use HTTPClient or Typhoeus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be a fitting task for [Typhoeus](http://github.com/pauldix/typhoeus)

Something like this (untested):

```
require 'typhoeus'

def write_file(filename, data)
    file = File.new(filename, "wb")
    file.write(data)
    file.close
      # ... some other stuff
end

hydra = Typhoeus::Hydra.new(:max_concurrency => 20)

batch_urls.each do |url_info|
    req = Typhoeus::Request.new(url_info[:url])
    req.on_complete do |response|
      write_file(url_info[:file], response.body)
    end
    hydra.queue req
end

hydra.run
```

Come to think of it, you might get a memory problem because of the enormous amout of files. One way to prevent that would be to never store the data in a variable but instead stream it to the file directly. You could use [em-http-request](http://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request) for that.

```
EventMachine.run {
  http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new('http://www.website.com/').get
  http.stream { |chunk| print chunk }
  # ...
}
```

Comment: Neat, seems to work very nicely! :-) I will try to test it during night (not to put down one of government sites) for at least 50-100k files to see how long does it take and to catch possible issues. It needs to be run periodically later. Thank you for your tip.

Answer (score 3):

So, if you don't set a on_body handler than curb will buffer the download.  If you're downloading files you should use an on_body handler.   If you want to download multiple files using Ruby Curl, try the Curl::Multi.download interface.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'curb'

urls_to_download = [
  'http://www.google.com/',
  'http://www.yahoo.com/',
  'http://www.cnn.com/',
  'http://www.espn.com/'
]
path_to_files = [
  'google.com.html',
  'yahoo.com.html',
  'cnn.com.html',
  'espn.com.html'
]

Curl::Multi.download(urls_to_download, {:follow_location => true}, {}, path_to_files) {|c,p|}
```

If you want to just download a single file.

```
Curl::Easy.download('http://www.yahoo.com/')
```

Here is a good resource: http://gist.github.com/405779

Answer (score 1):

There's been benchmarks done that has compared curb with other methods such as HTTPClient. The winner, in almost all categories was HTTPClient. Plus, there have been some documented scenarios where curb does NOT work in multi-threading scenarios.

Like you, I've had your experience. I ran system commands of curl in 20+ concurrent threads and it was 10 X fasters than running curb in 20+ concurrent threads. No matter, what I tried, this was always the case.

I've since then switched to HTTPClient, and the difference is huge. Now it runs as fast as 20 concurrent curl system commands, and uses less CPU as well.

Comment: add a link for HTTPClient?

Answer (score 0):

First let me say that I know almost nothing about Ruby.

What I do know is that Ruby is an interpreted language; it's not surprising that it's slower than heavily optimised code that's been compiled for a specific platform. Every file operation will probably have checks around it that `curl` doesn't. The "some other stuff" will slow things down even more.

Have you tried profiling your code to see where most of the time is being spent?

Comment: The Ruby Curl::Easy class methods are "wrappers" around libcurl C functions, all the downloading code is written in C. The additional call and interpreter overhead is negligible in this case.

Also note that executing curl command-line was faster and it includes process creation and other stuff (which is fast, but I believe is slower than Rubu interpreter function call).

Comment: @Stiivi, obviously some assumption you have made is wrong somewhere.  Probably this part: "the additional call and interpreter overhead is negligible."  Something is not negligible.  Probably taking the C strings and turning them into Ruby strings.

Answer (score 0):

Stiivi,

any chance that [Net::HTTP](http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html) would suffice for simple downloading of HTML pages?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a Ruby version, but threads in 1.8.x are user-space threads, not scheduled by the OS, so the entire Ruby interpreter only ever use one CPU/core. On top of that there is a Global Interpreter Lock, and probably other locks as well, interfering with concurrency. Since you're trying to maximize network throughput, you're probably underutilizing CPUs.

Spawn as many processes as the machine has memory for, and limit the reliance on threads.